# Solve $z^4+16=0$ where $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

The following exercise is related to complex numbers so $z$ is a complex number.
Can you please check whether I solved correctly the exercise.
$$z^4+16=0$$
$$z^4=16i^2$$
$$z^2=4i$$

I transformed the complex number $4i$ into the trigonometric form, and got:$$4(\cos(\pi +\pi k)+i\sin (\pi+\pi k))$$. So the result is:$$z=2\left[\cos{\left({\pi +\pi k \over 2}\right)}+i\sin\left ({\pi+\pi k\over 2}\right)\right]$$.

The only problem is that in my workbook the result is:
$$z=2\left[\cos{\left({\pi +2\pi k \over 4}\right)}+i\sin\left ({\pi+2\pi k\over 4}\right)\right]$$

I hope you'll help me find the mistake. Thank you that you are reflecting over my exercise !

Comment: The step that goes from $z^4=16i^2$ to $z^2=4i$ is incorrect.

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: That, and the fact that, later on, $4i\ne4(\cos(\pi +\pi k)+i\sin (\pi+\pi k))=\pm4$.

Comment: It's the same as saying $x^2=1$ gives $x=1$.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions?

Comment: $$4(\cos(\pi +\pi k)+i\sin (\pi+\pi k))$$ is not $4i$, it is $\pm 4$. Also, it should be $z^2=\pm 4i$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex numbers equation: $z^4 = -16$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/complex-numbers-equation-z4-16)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternate solution is to factor this way:

$$x^4+16 = (x^2+4)^2 - 8x^2 = (x^2+4+2\sqrt 2 x)(x^2+4-2\sqrt2 x)$$

And solve $x^2+2\sqrt2 x +4=0$ and $x^2-2\sqrt2 x +4=0$. This will give you the exact solutions:

$$x=\pm \sqrt 2 \pm i\sqrt 2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$z^4=-16$$
How $-1=e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)}$:
$$z^4=16 \exp\left(i(\pi+2k\pi)\right)$$
$$z=2 \exp\left(\frac{i(\pi+2k\pi)}{4}\right)$$

Comment: But what do you think about solving it as I started, in such a manner? Though I see your method is a real time-saver, thank you.

Comment: The answer to THAT, @JohnG., is in my comment to the main question.

Comment: @JohnG. in short $i^2=-1$ but $(-i)^2=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^4+16=0<=>$$
$$z^4=-16<=>$$
$$z^4=|-16|e^{arg(-16)i}<=>$$
$$z^4=16e^{(\pi +2\pi k)i}<=>$$

(with k is the element of Z)

$$z=\left(16e^{(\pi +2\pi k)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}<=>$$
$$z=2e^{\left(\frac{1}{4}\pi +\frac{1}{2}\pi k\right)i}$$

(with k goes from 0 to 3 -> k=0-3)