# What are the solutions to $z^4 = -25$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I can't remember complex roots. Can someone please refresh my memory and help me with the following?

> What are the solutions to the equation $z^4=-25$?

Comment: Polar form${}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex numbers equation: $z^4 = -16$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109063/complex-numbers-equation-z4-16)

Answer (score 1):

$$z^4=-25=5^2e^{(2m+1)\pi i}$$ where $m$ is any integer

$$\implies z=\sqrt5 e^{(2m+1)\pi i/4}$$ where $m\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$